# Writing data to cassandra using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka

I have a spark job written in Scala, in which I am just trying to write one line separated by commas, coming from Kafka producer to Cassandra database. **But I couldn't call saveToCassandra.** 
I saw few examples of wordcount where they are writing map structure to Cassandra table with two columns and it seems working fine. But I have many columns and I found that the data structure needs to parallelized. 
Here's is the sample of my code:

```
object TestPushToCassandra extends SparkStreamingJob {
def validate(ssc: StreamingContext, config: Config): SparkJobValidation = SparkJobValid

def runJob(ssc: StreamingContext, config: Config): Any = {

val bp_conf=BpHooksUtils.getSparkConf()
val brokers=bp_conf.get("bp_kafka_brokers","unknown_default")


val input_topics = config.getString("topics.in").split(",").toSet


val output_topic = config.getString("topic.out")


val kafkaParams = Map[String, String]("metadata.broker.list" -> brokers)
val messages = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, input_topics)


val lines = messages.map(_._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(","))

val li = words.par

li.saveToCassandra("testspark","table1", SomeColumns("col1","col2","col3"))
li.print()



words.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition(partition =>
    partition.foreach{
      case x:String=>{

        val props = new HashMap[String, Object]()
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers)
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
          "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
          "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")

        val outMsg=x+" from spark"
        val producer = new KafkaProducer[String,String](props)
        val message=new ProducerRecord[String, String](output_topic,null,outMsg)
        producer.send(message)
      }
    }


  )
)


ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
}
}
```

I think it's the syntax of Scala that I am not getting correct.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The call of words.par is almost certainly not the right thing to do. The Dstream "words" is already a DStream which is by it's nature already distributed and parallelized. What is the problem you have without that?

Comment: It works without ".par" but now I am wondering how am I gonna split the values to extract values of col1, col2, col3? For example, if inside kafka producer I write "val1,val2,val3", then how can I extract these values and store in col1, col2 and col3 respectively?

Comment: Are you saying you can't .split(",") the string?

Comment: Yes exactly. So basically if I pass "val1,val2,val3" from my producer, what should be the code of my variables "lines" and "words" in the above code so that I can call saveToCassandra on words variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your words `DStream` into something that the Connector can handle.

Like a Tuple

```
val words = lines
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map( wordArr => (wordArr(0), wordArr(1), wordArr(2))
```

or a Case Class

```
case class YourRow(col1: String, col2: String, col3: String)
val words = lines
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map( wordArr => YourRow(wordArr(0), wordArr(1), wordArr(2)))
```

or a CassandraRow

This is because if you place an Array there all by itself it could be an Array in C* you are trying to insert rather than 3 columns.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/5_saving.md

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I try to your solution, its storing bit differently in the database. Maybe I am missing some little syntax. From Kafka producer if I pass abc,def,ghi and here's my code:                    val lines = messages.map(_._2)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val innerWords = words.flatMap(_.split(","))
val wordCounts = innerWords.map(wordArr = (wordArr(0),wordArr(1),wordArr(2)))

wordCounts.saveToCassandra("keyspace01","table1", SomeColumns("col1","col2","col3"))
And this code results into three entries in the database, i.e. 1st: a,b,c 2nd: d,e,f 3rd: g,h,i

Comment: woops I shouldn't have copied your lines, that should be map and not flatMap

Comment: If I use map with words in the first place for splitting, then it gives me the compiler error in words.foreachRDD function at the line "case x:String". It says  scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type;
found   : String
required: Array[String]

Comment: Ah it worked, I just had to change that case from x:String to x:Array[String]. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: My next task would be to send csv files to kafka producer so spark job will manage to add them to database. Do you have resource that I can follow to achieve something like this?

Comment: No point in using Kafka if you just want to pipe to C*, just use fileStream from Spark Streaming.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it!